# antlr4 grammar- Help required for the grammar creation

Tags: grammar, antlr4

I would like to create a grammar for the following input:

LogFile = c:\folder\logfile.txt

or

LogFile = \192.168.120.120\folder\logfile.txt

The file path should contain a file extension.

See below my grammar:

```
grammar CustomLanguage;

autoTask : logFileCommand;
logFileCommand : 'LogFile' ASSIGNMENT PARAMETER_PATH_FILENAME;
ASSIGNMENT : '=';   
PARAMETER_PATH_FILENAME : ??????? FILE_EXTENSION ;

FILE_EXTENSION : '.'('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z');
```

What is the correct rule for PARAMETER_PATH_FILENAME?

PARAMETER_PATH_FILENAME : ??????? FILE_EXTENSION ;

Thanks

Comment: ANTLR is *not* the right tool for this. Just use a regex, it will be a one-liner.

Comment: I'm using the right tool, my grammar is not only this expression. I just don't know how to manage this expression. :-)

Comment: OK, then remember that ANTLR's lexical analysis pass is independent from the parser. Basically, with the grammar above, `LogFile` becomes a keyword of your language for instance. If you try to find a rule to validate filenames, you'll have issues later on (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/antlr/3271/lexer-rules-in-v4/11235/priority-rules#t=201701081110143641676) for a description of the issue). You should probably validate the file name *after* parsing, is a separate validation pass. But I can't help you more than that without seeing the full lexer grammar.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with an existing URL grammar like this one: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/url/url.g4 and extend the parts you need (namely adding backward slash support and a variation for file URLs - drive instead of protocol).